# Pyspark not abl to read catalog table from EMR

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue, emr-serverless

I need to read AWS glue catalog table from emr using pyspark. Please find the screenshot. It gives error like amazon s3 access denied exception. I am not doing anything with s3 in script.[image]

Comment: Hi! Can you [please read](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732) about the problems with images of text and then edit your question to add transcriptions of your images of text as actual text? Perhaps useful: [editing help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).